# Git Fork how to find who has forked into our repositories

Tags: git, github

I am in situation that, We had company project repositories, which was used by multiple member. One of our member has forked demo example repo in to our repositories. Is there any way to find who has forked github demo example project into company project repo and date or time.Please it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your company has an origanisation, then the owner of that organization can [review  the audit log](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization).

If the fork was created in the past 90 days, an `operation:create` entry, which lists all events where a resource was created, will be there.